# Can curl be used to upload package or bundle to Sling

Tags: curl, aem, sling

I know that maven-build-plugin internally uses curl and hit a POST request to service.jsp page, like this call

```
curl -u <uid>:<pwd> -X POST
http://localhost:7402/crx/packmgr/service/.json/etc/packages/mycontent.zip?cmd=create 
-d packageName=<name> -d groupName=<name>
```

to upload and install package in cq. I'm not able to find any way to install my package on Sling this way.
is there any way so i don't have to manually install package in Sling ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$CURL -X POST -s $HOST/etc/packages/mypackages/$FILENAME?cmd=install
```

Check out this post on the subject too:
https://cqdump.wordpress.com/2014/03/10/using-curl-to-install-cq-packages-and-why-it-isnt-a-good-idea/

It has some useful points to consider on how this could lead to some issues.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. Learned something new. but my original question still remains. The other day i was doing Sling Dynamic Include and i had to build and deploy the bundle manually. is there any way i could automate this step with Sling(as i do with CQ via autoInstallPackage profile)?

Comment: I understood your original question to be something like "Can curl be used to install a package I have uploaded?"  So I thought this answered that.  You can install by using a curl POST to the package, with the cmd=install querystring.

Comment: Because AEM/CQ is built on REST principles, you can monitor your browser network traffic to discover this and many other tricks that can be replicated in curl (or other HttpClients)